# What do these certain symbols/parts mean in preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

I know a little about `preg_match`, however there are some that look rather complex and some that contain symbols that I don't entirely understand. For example:

**On the first one** - I can only assume this has something to do with an e-mail address and url, but what do things like `[^/]` and the `?` mean?

```
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $variable);
```

.....

**In the second one** -  what do things like the `^`, `{5}` and `$` mean?

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$/", $variable);
```

It's just these small things I'm not entirely sure on and a brief explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the direct answers. I kept them short because they won't make sense without an understanding of regex. That understanding is best gained at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html. I advise you to also try out the regex helper tools listed there, they allow you to experiment - see live capturing/matching as you edit the pattern, very helpful.

Simple parentheses ( ) around something makes it a group. Here you have (?=) which is an assertion, specifically a positive look ahead assertion. All it does is check whether what's inside actually exists forward from the current cursor position in the haystack. Still with me?
Example: foo(?=bar) matches foo only if followed by bar. bar is never matched, only foo is returned.

With this in mind, let's dissect your regex:

```
 /^.*(?=.{4,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/

Reads as:
    ^.* From Start, capture 0-many of any character
(?=.{4,}) if there are at least 4 of anything following this
(?=.*[0-9]) if there is: 0-many of any, ending with an integer following
(?=.*[a-z]) if there is: 0-many of any, ending with a lowercase letter following
(?=.*[A-Z]) if there is: 0-many of any, ending with an uppercase letter following
    .*$ 0-many of anything preceding the End
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not a fan of just posting links, I think a regex tutorial would be too much. So check out this [Regular Expression cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v1/png/) it will probably get you on your way if you already have a little understanding of what it does.

Also check out this for some explanations and more helpful links; http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/01/essential-guide-to-regular-expressions-tools-tutorials-and-resources/

Answer (score 1):

First one:

The `@` actually don't have anything to do with the content that is matched. Usually, you use `/` as the delimiter character in a regex. Downside is, that you need to escape it everytime you want to use it. So here, `@` is used as the delimiter.

`[^/]` is a character group. `[/]` would match only the `/` character, `^` inverts this. `[^/]` matches all characters *except* the `/`.

Second one:

`^` matches the beginning of the string, `$` the end of the string. You can use this to enforce that the regex has to apply to the whole string you are matching on.

`{5}` is a quantifier. It is equivalent to `{5,5}` which is `minimum 5, maximum 5`, so it matches exactly 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

first one:
`[^/]` = everything but no slash

second one:
`^` look from beginning of $variable
`{5}` exactly 5 occurencies of [A-Z]
`$` look until end of $variable reached

combination of `^ and $` means that everything between that has to apply to $variable